# Testing successful seed with minitest / rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to test if a seed is successfully run. I currently have the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SeedsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'it should successfully run the seeds' do
    assert_nothing_raised(Exception) { load Rails.root.join('db/seeds.rb') }
  end
end
```

However the load expression simply returns true and does not invoke the seed.
Is there a way to do this?

**edit:**
I tried running it as a rake test, but it gave me the same.

```
assert_nothing_raised(Exception) { Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test file, instead of writing

```
assert_nothing_raised(Exception) { load Rails.root.join('db/seeds.rb') }
```

try

```
assert_nothing_raised(Exception) {load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"}
```